# Undefined elements in struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault

I am creating a client/server application and want to call functions dynamically. i have create the following struct:

```
typedef struct _cmd cmd;
struct _cmd
{
    const char *name;
    void (*func)(int s,int ac, char **av);
};
```

When the client send a command to the server the server will browse through an array of commands:

```
cmd cmds[] = {
        { "CREATE", cmd_create },
        { "EXIT" ,  cmd_exit },
        { "LIST", cmd_list },
        { "READ", cmd_read },
        { "DELETE", cmd_delete },
        { "UPDATE", cmd_update }
};


cmd *find_cmd(const char *name) {
    cmd *c;
    for (c = cmds; c->name; c++) {
        if (stricmp(name, c->name) == 0)
            return c;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Please not that

```
stricmp()
```

is not a typo, it a case-insensitive version of strcmp.

I now the following problem. When I call find_cmd() and pass an invalid commmand, my application crashes. my debugging messages showed the following:

```
Browsing Command: CREATE
Browsing Command: EXIT
Browsing Command: LIST
Browsing Command: READ
Browsing Command: DELETE
Browsing Command: UPDATE
Browsing Command: �p�
Browsing Command: �(�
```

After that i get the segfault. This looks to me as if there are some undefined elements in that struct arraym but where do they come from? What am I overlooking? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: You need a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to terminate your command list. Since this is a struct, null command and null function pointer will work.

Comment: Not the answer but just note. Don't use identifier starting with `_` because it's reserved for implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, this works fine, see my comment below :)

Comment: Also, I like as this thread is well-written, well-structured and is very clear what the author is looking for. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a "null" element at the end of your list to trigger the `c->name` (`!= NULL`) test in your for loop.

Change

```
cmd cmds[] = {
        { "CREATE", cmd_create },
        { "EXIT" ,  cmd_exit },
        { "LIST", cmd_list },
        { "READ", cmd_read },
        { "DELETE", cmd_delete },
        { "UPDATE", cmd_update }
};
```

to

```
cmd cmds[] = {
        { "CREATE", cmd_create },
        { "EXIT" ,  cmd_exit },
        { "LIST", cmd_list },
        { "READ", cmd_read },
        { "DELETE", cmd_delete },
        { "UPDATE", cmd_update },
        { NULL, NULL }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this works as a charme. 

How come I need to explicitly add a NULL, NULL element to the list? I'm not checking for (c->name == NULL) but return NULL when nothing was found?

Comment: But you _are_ testing `c->name == NULL`. That's the termination condition on your `for` loop. That's what the center expression on the `for` statement does.

Comment: @Fish-Guts, your loop termination condition is `c->name` i.e `c->name != NULL`. By adding the sentinel `NULL` element, it allows the `for` loop to exit.